# writing from excel vba to IE

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I want to input some text into IE. I used the inspect element from Chrome to get the `id` to track the input and I get:

Here's my code:

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate ("http://customerservice.ciena.com/BidRegister/Search.aspx")

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

For Each element In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    Debug.Print element.ID
    If element.Type = "Text" And element.ID = "ctl00_P1_ucSearchFilter_txtBidNumber" Then
    element.Value = "LA-2013-0233"
    End If

Next element
```

The problem is that I cannot find that ID anymore using the debug.print. Can anyone tell me a different way to write my input?

Comment: Can you post the source code of that `Input` field?

Comment: i m not familiar with this kind of coding, tell me what i should be looking for and i ll post it. does this help: <div id="HeaderSearch">
<a title="Ciena Order Number">Bid #:</a>
<input name="ctl00$Header1$txtQuickSearch" type="text" id="ctl00_Header1_txtQuickSearch" style="width:80px;">
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$Header1$btnSearch" value="Search" id="ctl00_Header1_btnSearch" class="buttonHeader"></div>
</div>

Comment: The ID that you are using is `ctl00_P1_ucSearchFilter_txtBidNumber` and based on what I understood from the source code is you need to use `ctl00_Header1_txtQuickSearch`. Trying changing it.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this one and worked:

```
For Each elemento In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
   If elemento.Name = "ctl00$Header1$txtQuickSearch" Then
        elemento.Value = "LA-2013-0233"
        Exit For
   End If
Next elemento
```

thanks!